# lightning:recordForm - Error when layout contains recordTypeId

Tags: lightning-aura-components, page-layout, lightning-record-form

I have a component that contains lightning:recordForm like so:

```
<lightning:recordForm  
        recordId="001f200001Zg2uYAAR"                  
        objectApiName="Account"
        layoutType="Compact"
        columns="3"
        mode="edit" />
```

If the layout that is rendered contains "Account Record Type" the following error is displayed at the top of the form:

> Field: RecordTypeId is not a valid lookup field.

Is this a known issue?  I have not seen other reports of this.

Comment: I observed this too. You may need to reach out to the Salesforce support.

Comment: Yes, had the same issue. Best to raise a case with Salesforce.

Comment: Does this org have Account Record Types defined?

Comment: Yes @JeremyNottingham, there are Account Record Types defined.

Answer (score 2):

I had a conversation with Salesforce support about this.  Its a known issue but there is no timeline on fixing it

Edit
@Homerlex I found a workaround
if you find the proper record type Id in the init method of your component and save it to an attribute variable called recordTypeId and then update your lighting record form to this, it should remove the error

Component

```
<lightning:recordForm 
        aura:Id="createAcct" 
        recordId="001f200001Zg2uYAAR"                  
        objectApiName="Account"
        layoutType="Compact"
        columns="3"
        mode="edit"
        onSubmit="{!c.handleSave}" />
```

Controller

```
handleSave : function(cmp, event, helper){
        event.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
        var eventFields = event.getParam("fields");
        eventFields['RecordTypeId'] = cmp.get('v.recordTypeId');
        cmp.find('createAcct').submit(eventFields);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @CalvinOKeefe.  I opened a case with support and they haven't given me an answer yet.

Comment: let me know if they tell you something different if you ever hear back from them!

Answer (score -1):

You just need to take the record type off of the page layout that you are using.  You will spot getting the error.

Comment: Thats not always possible from a requirements standpoint